# Finding the number of decimal strings that have "runs" of given length

Tags: python

I am stuck on a problem where I want to find the number of decimal strings of length n (each of the n digits can be 0,1,...9) that have at least a 'run' of `length >= k`. 'Runs' are consecutively incrementing/decrementing sequences of digits that can overflow/underflow mod 10. For example, '345600', '901285', '098723' all have runs of length 4, but '123890' only has two runs of length 3.

My idea is to iterate over each of the `10^n` possible candidates. I know for each candidate you have to check `n-k+1` 'blocks' of `k` digits to see whether they're 'incrementing' or 'decrementing'.

```py
def checkinc(inputstring, straightlength):
    for startdigit in range(len(inputstring)-straightlength+1):
        for i in range(straightlength):
            if int(inputstring[startdigit+i]) != (int(inputstring[startdigit]) + i)%10:
                return False
    return True
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a function to check 'incrementing mod 10'. Currently, this function returns False too easily. Perhaps I'm missing a standard trick I haven't learned yet, or is there a simple recursion method to do this? Thanks for any guidance.

It's my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. Please let me know how I could ask a question better in the future.

Comment: Maybe try coming up with a less brute-force solution on paper before getting into that kind of implementation detail.

Comment: thank you @Ry- I will try to figure it out, perhaps by trying an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Digits a,b are in an increasing sequence when (a-b+10)%10 equals 1 or in a decreasing sequence if it equals 9. Any other value indicates that they are not in sequence.

You could create a dictionary of pairs that will tell if two consecutive characters are part of an increasing(1) or decreasing(9) run.  Then process each pair of characters in your string to convert them into run indicators.  If you find consecutive "1" or "9" indicators for a length of N-1 then you know you have at least one run of length N:

```
def hasRun(string,count):
    match = {(str(n),str((n+d)%10)):str(d) for d in [1,9] for n in range(10) }
    runs  =  "".join( match.get(pair,".") for pair in zip(string,string[1:]) )
    return "1"*(count-1) in runs or "9"*(count-1) in runs
```

Another way to approach this would be to search for the 20 possible runs of length N in the string (10 increasing and their 10 inverse):

```
def hasRun(string,count):
    for i in range(10):
        run = "".join(str((d+i)%10) for d in range(count))
        if run in string or run[::-1] in string: return True
    return False
```

Finally, if you need a procedural approach, you could do it like this:

```
def hasRun(string,count):
    runType  = 0
    runCount = 0
    match = {(str(n),str((n+d)%10)):d for d in [1,9] for n in range(10) }
    for a,b in zip(string,string[1:]):
        delta    = match.get((a,b),0)
        runCount = 2 if delta != runType else runCount + 1
        if delta != 0 and runCount == count:
            return True
        runType  = delta
    return False
```

*Note: This procedural approach runs in O(n) time. It will often execute faster than the other two when it finds a run of the requested length early in the string.  This is because it stops iterating immediately and does not process the rest of the string.*